# php nested array for json output

Tags: php, arrays, json

I run queries on 3 tables and I'm trying to format results into a nested array. It's the inner array thats got me stumped. sizes array should be in the beer array object but its outside of it. Any help appreciated.

JSON

```
    {
    "brewerId": "41", 
    "brewerName": "Prancing Pony Brewing", 
    "beers": [
        {
            "beerid": "816", 
            "productName": "Prancing Pony Amber Ale", 
            "ibu": "18.00", 
            "abv": "5.00", 
            "style": "Amber Ale"
        }, 
        {
            "beerid": "817", 
            "productName": "Prancing Pony Copper Ale", 
            "ibu": "25.00", 
            "abv": "5.80", 
            "style": "Indian Pale Ale"
        }, 
        {
            "beerid": "837", 
            "productName": "Prancing Pony Pale Ale", 
            "ibu": "37.00", 
            "abv": "5.50",  
            "style": "Pale Ale"
        }, 
        {
            "beerid": "838", 
            "productName": "Prancing Pony India Red Ale", 
            "ibu": "60.00", 
            "abv": "7.90", 
            "style": "Indian Pale Ale"
        }
    ], 
    "sizes": [
        {
            "beerId": "816", 
            "size": "330ml Bottle"
        }, 
        {
            "beerId": "816", 
            "size": "330ml Can"
        }, 
        {
            "beerId": "837", 
            "size": "345ml Can"
        }, 
        {
            "beerId": "837", 
            "size": "375ml Bottle"
        }
    ]
},
```

PHP

```
    $result = $func->getBrewers(); 
    $json_response = array(); 
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $row_array = array();
        $row_array['brewerId'] = $row['brewerId'];        
        $row_array['brewerName'] = $row['brewerName'];
        $row_array['beers'] = array();
        $brewer_pk = $row['brewerId'];  

        $beer_qry = $func->getBeers($brewer_pk);
        while ($beer_fet = mysqli_fetch_array($beer_qry))
        {
            $row_array['beers'][] = array(
            'beerid' => $beer_fet['beerid'],
            'productName' => $beer_fet['productName'],
            'ibu' => $beer_fet['ibu'],
            'abv' => $beer_fet['abv'],
            'notes' => $beer_fet['notes'],
            'style' => $beer_fet['style'],

        );

        $beer_pk = $beer_fet['beerid'];
        $size_qry = $func->getSizes($beer_pk);
        while ($size_fet = mysqli_fetch_array($size_qry))
        {
            $row_array['sizes'][] = array(
            'beerId' => $size_fet['beerId'],
            'size' => $size_fet['size'],
            );
        }
    }

    array_push($json_response, $row_array);
    }
    echo json_encode($json_response);
```

Comment: Performance and scalability of this approach sucks big time. Run a single joined query and build the nesting as you parse the rows returned.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you misindented at some point and just went wrong from that point on.

```
$result = $func->getBrewers(); 
$json_response = array(); 
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $row_array = array(
        'brewerId'   => $row['brewerId'],
        'brewerName' => $row['brewerName'],
        'beers'      => array()
    );

    $brewer_pk = $row['brewerId'];  
    $beer_qry = $func->getBeers($brewer_pk);
    while ($beer_fet = mysqli_fetch_array($beer_qry))
    {
        $tmp = array(
            'beerid'      => $beer_fet['beerid'],
            'productName' => $beer_fet['productName'],
            'ibu'         => $beer_fet['ibu'],
            'abc'         => $beer_fet['abv'],
            'notes'       => $beer_fet['notes'],
            'style'       => $beer_fet['style'],
            'sizes'       => array()
        );

        $beer_pk = $tmp['beerid'];
        $size_qry = $func->getSizes($beer_pk);
        while ($size_fet = mysqli_fetch_array($size_qry))
        {
            $tmp['sizes'][] = array(
                'beerId' => $size_fet['beerId'],
                'size'   => $size_fet['size'],
            );
        }

        $row_array['beers'][] => $tmp;
    }

    array_push($json_response, $row_array);
}

echo json_encode($json_response);
```

In order to simplify the referencing somewhat, I've rewritten the beers to be created in a `$tmp` variable, which now also has a `'sizes'` array to which the various sizes will be appended.
After the beers and sizes are added, the `$tmp` will be added to the beers.

Do note that you will now be performing some more database queries, as it now (as requested) fetches the sizes per beer and not just for the last one.